# PHP: Generate number according to the format (string)

Tags: php

I just made a settings section in my app that has the parameter as `invoice_number_format`. The parameter itself stores the string, like this: `YYYY-mm/ii`, where Y - the current year (I'm using Carbon), m - month number and i = invoice ID (DB auto increment).

The problem is that I can not think of the logic on how to convert this string to a number. For instance, there are separate options available, like:

```
YY-mm/iiii // Must be converted to 20-12/0001
YYYY-mm/ii // Must be converted to 2020-12/1
// and other variation with different delimiters (/ and -).
```

I am sure there is no any built in PHP method (or even Laravel) to convert this string to a formatted number. I could use the simple `str_split` or even `explode`, but the delimiter may vary. And the problem also with the count of each symbol - if there is `YY`, then put the `20`, otherwise put the full year - like this.

May be you could also suggest me other format to store this string, like `{full_year}-{month}/{index}` or something like that and how to generate the number, based on this string?

Kind regards.

Comment: Can these formats be mixed in a way that puts the id somewhere in the middle or can it only be at the start/end?

Comment: @El_Vanja, nope - these IDs are only at the start or at the end. Divided with "/" OR with "-"

Comment: In that case, you could let Carbon deal with the date part of the format and merely append/prepend the id. How are these strings created? Dynamically by the user or are they controlled by you and you only offer users the templates to choose from?

Comment: @El_Vanja, the user can select from available options (simple select field). And once selected and saved to the DB, this parameter can't be edited anymore (since legally, the invoice ID format should not change over time). But what about the dilimiter? it is still unknown. I mean it can be '-' or '/'

Comment: One more thing - what exactly is the rule on the number of `i`s in the format? You say `iiii` should translate to `0001` (four digits), but `ii` translates to a single one?

Comment: `iiii` is with trailing zeroes, so it must always have 4 digits (like 0018). `ii` allows it to be just the number (like 18).

Comment: So only those two options are available for the id, nothing else?

Comment: That's correct! There is no problem to add trailing zeroes - the main question is how to convert overall format

Comment: That's a pretty elegant solution. You can post it as an aswer to your own question. Just one thing: those are leading zeroes, not trailing.

Comment: @El_Vanja, thank you! Yeah, it was my mistake - misused the word. It happens when you speak 3 languages during a day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question did not get any answers and it seems that I found a solution by myself, I will post it here, in case this question helps someone later.

There is a `strtr()` PHP native method. I could implement it like this:

```
// Assuming the $year = 2020 and $month = 12 and $index = 5
$trans = [
  "YY" => $fullYear, // via Carbon;
  "YYYY" => $shortYear, // via Carbon;
  "mm" => $month, // via Carbon;
  "ii" => $index, // already known number;
  "iiii" => addLeadingZeros($index) // the function to add leading zeros here.
];

echo strtr("YY-mm/iiii", $trans); // Returns 20-12/0005
```

Putting a bit different format:

```
echo strtr("YYYY-mm/ii") // Returns 2020-12/5.
```